# How to plot a line graph with data points in Python?

Tags: python

I attached an example of the line graph. I tried to use the data in the DataFrame to plot such a line graph in Python, but my x-axis and y-axis are messed up.

Can someone show how to plot a nice line graph like that with data points on it? Also, more useful parameters are highly preferred.

For the graph, I will use 'Date' as my x-axis, and 'Common Shares Issued' as my y-axis.

Thank you very much

This is the sample line graph

[image: This is the sample line graph]

This is what the DataFrame looks like

[image: This is what the DataFrame looks like]

Comment: Then, do you want to plot `Common Shares Issued` over `Date`, with ylabel?

Comment: I have to apologize, but I think you might misunderstand my question^^

That line graph is a screen shot from a website, I downloaded the raw data, and I want to use Python coding to REGENERATE this line graph. Thanks a lot. Hope it does make sense:)